# calculating fibonacci numbers in java

Tags: java, view, model, controller, fibonacci

I am trying to display the first 20 fibbonacci numbers using the model view controller method in java. However the output that I am getting is only the last number(the first 19 are not displaying) if anyone is able to look through my code and point out where im going wrong that would be awesome :)

public class FibonacciModel {

```
public String fibModel(int a, int b, int c, int count){
    String result = "";
    //int c;
    while(count!=20)  // if you want first 100 fibonacci numbers then change 20 to 100 accordingly 
    {
        c=a+b;
        count++;
        result = c + " ";
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

public class FibonacciController {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int count = 2;
    int c = 0;



    FibonacciModel Model = new FibonacciModel();
    FibonacciView View = new FibonacciView();

    View.say(Model.fibModel(a, b, c, count));


}
```

}

```
public class FibonacciView {
    public < T > void say( T word ){
        System.out.print(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to do some debugging, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your result variable. Try `result = result + c + " ";` or `result += c + " ";`

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :)

```
public static void getFibbonacci(int n){
        int total = 0;
        int prev = 1;        
        for (int x=1; x<n; x++){
            total = total + prev;
            prev = total - prev;

            System.out.println(total);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class fibbo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    a = sc.nextInt();
    int first = 0;
    int second = 1;
    int third;
    System.out.print("Fibbonacci series is= ");
    System.out.print("\t" + first + "\t" + second + "\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < a - 2; i++) {
        third = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = third;
        System.out.print(third + "\t");
    }

}
```